# Index of covering in covering group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, covering-spaces

In wikipedia I read:

> In mathematics, a covering group of a topological group $H$ is a covering space $G$ of $H$ such that $G$ is a topological group and the covering map $p : G \rightarrow H$ is a continuous group homomorphism. The map $p$ is called the covering homomorphism. A frequently occurring case is a double covering group, a topological double cover in which $H$ has index 2 in $G$; examples include the Spin groups, Pin groups, and metaplectic groups.

In this definition $H$ is not necessary a subgroup of $G$ (so "$H$ has index 2 in $G$" doesn't make sense in the usual way). So my question is: what is "the index of $H$ in $G$" in this context?

Comment: It's just a speculation, perhaps by saying covering map they mean that $p^{-1}(H)$ is homeomorphic to a disjoint union of spaces homeomorphic to $H$. If so the index is the number of such spaces.

Comment: Maybe is $[G:p^{-1}(H)]=2$

Comment: that's less likely. If you consider $G=H\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with the map $p(h,a) = h$ then $p^{-1}(H)=G$ so by your definition the index is $1$ which in my opinion makes less sense than saying that $p^{-1}(H) = H\times\{0\}\bigsqcup H\times\{1\}$ and so the index is $2$ (As the usual index).

Comment: Maybe $[G:p^{-1}(H)]$ is always 1 because, if I'm not wrong, $p$ is surjective by definition then $p^{-1}(H)=G$. Here: 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space

says $p$ is surjective.

Comment: Wikipedia is just plain wrong on this. I traced the incorrect statement to the January 2009 revision.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You should explain more precisely what you want to know. "In this definition $H$ is not necessary a subgroup of $G$." Do you mean that **if** $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then what  can be said about $[G: H]$?

Comment: Ok, I would to know what "$H$ has index 2 in $G$" means in that definition.

Comment: The question currently has 4 votes to close. I cannot understand why this is, apart from perhaps that the question is not initially clear. I have tried to make the question clearer (although I am unsure if my edit improve readability - anyone should feel free to edit it!).

Answer (score 3):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

As Moishe Cohen pointed out in his comment, the phrase "A frequently occurring case is a double covering group, a topological double cover in which $H$ has index $2$ in $G$" appeared for the first time in the January 2009 revision of the Wikipedia article and it is **wrong**.

In general $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$, and it does not even embed as a subgroup into $G$. Therefore it does not make sense to speak about the index of $H$ in $G$.

Only in the trivial case $G = H  \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ there would be a reasonable interpretation.